# What is unknown construction in this code?

Tags: angularjs, jinja2

I tried to translate project oppia.org 
The code (angularJs, in template) has some things - `<[stateName]>`, I dont understant its construction `<[]>`. is It a variable? or is it a directive? is It a scope? Where is its value?

Code:

```
<h4 ng-if="!stateNameEditorIsShown" ng-click="openStateNameEditor()" class="oppia-editable-section">
   <[stateName]>
   <span ng-if="editabilityService.isEditable()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil oppia-editor-pencil" title="Edit State Name"></span>
</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since jinja2 and angularjs both want to use `{{` and `}}` for interpolation, one of them has to give. It's unclear from this example if that's angularjs or jinja2. If you explore the code you're translating, and find something like

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']>');
```

then it's angularjs code that's using the alternative binding markers.

**Edited to add:**

See https://code.google.com/p/oppia/source/browse/core/templates/dev/head/app.js lines 38-39. That's where angularjs is being configured to use alternate binding markers.

Comment: Just a heads-up, `startSymbol` and `endSymbol` are methods.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. That's what I get for relying on memory.

Comment: No problem, I know the feeling. I had to check myself :)

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
In file feconf.py:

`DEFAULT_INIT_STATE_NAME = 'First Stage'`

Answer (score 0):

Neither. This is the alternative interpolation markup that your oppia.org code has been configured to use. I guess one of your programmers didn't like the default `{{...}}` mustache syntax and they went with `<[...]>` instead. The value will come from the same place as with the standard `{{...}}` markup.

Find this in your code and it will make more sense:

```
oppia.config([ "$interpolateProvider","$httpProvider",
  function(a,b){
    a.startSymbol("<[");
    a.endSymbol("]>");
    ... ... ...
```

API doc on `$interpolateProvider` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider
Hope this helps.